# So I have this code here, it calculates the vowels in a given phrase. I'm trying to get it to repeat if the user says yes

Tags: java, loops, repeat

I was wondering as to how I could get the end of the program to repeat if the user does respond with a 1. Do I need to reorganize it so that it is part of the if statement?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Count Vowels \n============");
System.out.println("Type a sentence and this program will tell you\n\nhow many vowels there are (excluding 'y'):");
String string1;

string1 = input.nextLine();
string1 = string1.toLowerCase();
int vowels = 0;
int answer;
int i = 0;

for (String Vowels : string1.split(" ")) {
    for (i = 0; i < Vowels.length(); i++) {

        int letter = Vowels.charAt(i);

        if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i' || letter == 'o' || letter == 'u') {
            vowels++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Vowels.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + Vowels.substring(1) + " has " + vowels + " vowels");
    vowels = 1;
}

System.out.println("Would you like to check another phrase in the Vowel Counter? if so Press 1 if not press 2");
answer = input.nextInt();

if (answer == 1) {
    System.out.println("You have chosen to count the vowels in another phrase");
} else {
    System.out.println("Have a nice day");
}
```

Comment: Not clearing `Scanner` buffer perhaps?

Comment: You should look up what `do/while` loops are and how they work. Then you can repeat your program while the user enters `1`.

Comment: You can use a while loop...as long as the user enters 1 the program continues else the program breaks out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `do/while` loop. The skeleton for this kind of loop looks like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    // do your stuff here

    System.out.println("Would you like to check another phrase in the Vowel Counter? if so Press 1 if not press 2");
} while(input.nextInt() == 1);

System.out.println("Have a nice day");
```

It asks the user and evaluates the entered number in the `while(input.nextInt() == 1)` statement. If this comparison returns `true` (i.e. user entered `1`), then the loops starts again. If not (i.e. user entered something else than `1`), the loop stops and you'll get the "Good Bye" message instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering it really helped, but when I ran the program i got this error java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1

Comment: @dappers This exception occurs if you're trying to access an index that is greater than the string length. For example here `Vowels.substring(0, 1)` (if `Vowels` is empty) or here `Vowels.charAt(i)` (if `i` is `1` and `Vowels` contains only on character, which is on index `0`).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. A search on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=java+loop+until+condition+met&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) would have lead you to the correct answer in less time than it took you to ask the question. However, since you took the time to ask the question here is the answer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = 0;
        System.out.println("Count Vowels \n============");

        // the do-while loop ensures that the code is executed at least once
        do {
            // on the first run answer equals zero, but on other runs it will equal one
            if(answer == 1) {
                System.out.println("You have chosen to count the vowels in another phrase");
            }

            System.out.println("Type a sentence and this program will tell you\n\nhow many vowels there are (excluding 'y'):");
            String string1;

            string1 = input.nextLine();
            string1 = string1.toLowerCase();

            int vowels = 0;
            int i = 0;

            for (String Vowels : string1.split(" ")) {
                for (i = 0; i < Vowels.length(); i++) {

                    int letter = Vowels.charAt(i);
                    if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i'
                            || letter == 'o' || letter == 'u') {
                        vowels++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(Vowels.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                        + Vowels.substring(1) + " has " + vowels + " vowels");
                vowels = 1;
            }

            System.out.println("Would you like to check another phrase in the Vowel Counter? If so type 1 if not type 2 and press enter");
            answer = input.nextInt();
        } while (answer == 1);

        System.out.println("Have a nice day");
    }

}
```

In your code you assert that a letter is a vowel if it is in the set `a, e, i, o and u` which is true. However, the letter `y` can be a vowel in certain situations.

> In general, the Y is a consonant when the syllable already has a vowel. Also, the Y is considered a consonant when it is used in place of the soft J sound, such as in the name Yolanda or Yoda.
>   In the names Bryan and Wyatt, the Y is a vowel, because it provides the only vowel sound for the first syllable of both names. For both of these names, the letter A is part of the second syllable, and therefore does not influence the nature of the Y.

You could expand on your code even more by checking if the letter `y` is a vowel or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can split this up into more than one method and using one primary method call other methods inside a while loop. for example:

```
boolean continueCounting = false;

void countingVowels() {

 //some start game method to make continueCounting = true
 //something like "press 1 to start"
 //if (input == 1) { continueCounting = true; }

 while(continueCounting) {

  String userInput = getUserInput(); 
  countVowels(userInput); //count vowels in word from user input and prints them out to console
  getPlayAgainDecision(); //ask user to put 1 or 2

  if (answer == 1) {
   continue
  } else if (answer == 2) {
   continueCounting = false;
  } else {
   System.out.println("incorrect input, please choose 1 or 2");
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more elegant way to do the counting (I updated the code to satisfy Johnny's comment that my previous answer didn't answer OP's question. The code now loops without unnecessary code):

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    int answer = 0;
    Scanner input = null;
    do
    {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type a sentence and this program will tell you\nhow many vowels there are (excluding 'y'):");
        String sentence = input.nextLine();

        int vowels = 0;
        String temp = sentence.toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
        {
            switch((char)temp.charAt(i))
            {
                case 'A':
                case 'E':
                case 'I':
                case 'O':
                case 'U':
                    vowels++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The sentence: \"" + sentence + "\" has " + vowels + " vowels");
        System.out.print("Would you like to check another phrase in the Vowel Counter? if so Press 1 if not press any other key... ");
        String tempNum = input.next();
        try
        {
            answer = Integer.parseInt(tempNum);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            answer = 0;
        }
        System.out.println();
    } while (answer == 1);
    input.close();
    System.out.println("Have a nice day");
}
```

Notice that at the end, I catch a NumberFormatException for more robustness validation of the user's input.

Comment: very nice way to count

Comment: An even more elegant approach, without the need to cast: `for (char c : sentence.toCharArray()) {
           switch (c) {
              case 'a':
                  case 'e':
                  case 'i':
                  case 'o':
                  case 'u':
                      count++;
          break;
          default:
                  // no count increment
          }

       }`

Comment: Also the OP's question is about getting the code to repeat based on user input. Not an elegant approach to counting.

Comment: Part of the OP's problem is the unnecessary processing: For example, `for (String Vowels : string1.split(" ")) {}` does absolutely nothing. To count vowels, the input doesn't need to be split into words. This snippet shows that.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the main `for` loop inside a `do-while` loop, like so:

```
do
{
    for (String Vowels : string1.split(" ")) {
        for (i = 0; i < Vowels.length(); i++) {

            int letter = Vowels.charAt(i);

            if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i' || letter == 'o' || letter == 'u') {
                vowels++;
            }
        }

    System.out.println(Vowels.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
        Vowels.substring(1) + " has " + vowels + " vowels");
    vowels = 1;

    System.out.println("Would you like to check another phrase in the Vowel Counter? if so Press 1 if not press 2");
    answer = input.nextInt();
    }
} while (answer == 1);
System.out.println("Have a nice day");
```

Additionally, there are better ways to do the counting, for example:

```
for (char c : string1.toCharArray())
{
    c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
    if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
        count++;
}
```